# why mysql returns true when false

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem. like this, this code `DELETE FROM guru WHERE id=2` return true when in database `mysql`. only there data with id=1 in `mysql`. should return false because id=2 in syntax above. so I confuse, help me please. I'm sorry my English less fluent.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: This is absolutely ok.If query successfully then it will return true even there is no data modification is done.

Answer (score 6):

The `DELETE` operation will be successful if the syntax is correct and the table `guru` exists in the database you're connected to. A `false` is what happens specifically when a query encounters *an error* and requesting a deletion on rows that don't exist is not an error.

What you want to do is check how many rows were affected by your query, as if that's zero then it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

MySql delete query returns true in case of success and false in case of failures. If there is no row meeting the criteria then also it returns true.

In your case you will have to get the No of deleted rows to find out whether any row has deleted or not.

Comment: No, you can't use `mysql_affected_rows` in PHP because they deleted it.

Comment: @tadman: I am too aware of that but in question it is not much clear  about the platform and so on so it is just for eg.

Comment: An example is fine, but one that at least works is better.

Comment: never push that `mysql_` junk. Which means get off it yourself :p